# unable to insert details into table through INSERT query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a application form. When trying to enter details through form a error pop ups saying "Duplicate field '' for key 'empuser'" and whenever i tried to enter different username the condition "Username already existed" is only executing. I have tried all the possible solutions but could not rectify the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Here is my code
**empdetails.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "//W3C//DTDHTML4.01Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Employee Details</title>
    <style>
    #r{
        color:red;
    }
    #g{
        color:green;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="empdetails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id = "myForm" action="updatedetails.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Employee Name:
                    <input type="text" name="empname" id="empname" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email Id:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required />
                    <span class="error" id="user-result"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address:
                    <input type="text" name="addr" id="addr" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country
                    <select name="country" id="country" required>
                        <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Country </option>
                        <option id="coun1" value="coun1">Country1</option>
                        <option id="coun2" value="coun2">Country2</option>
                        <option id="coun3" value="coun3">Country3</option>
                        <option id="coun4" value="coun4">Country4</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>State
                    <select name="state"  id="state" required>
                        <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose State </option>
                        <option class="st1" value="st1">State1</option>
                        <option class="st1" value="st1">State2</option>
                        <option class="st1" value="st1">State3</option>
                        <option class="st1" value="st1">State4</option>
                        <option class="st2" value="st2">State5</option>
                        <option class="st2" value="st2">State6</option>
                        <option class="st2" value="st2">State7</option>
                        <option class="st2" value="st2">State8</option>
                        <option class="st3" value="st3">State9</option>
                        <option class="st3" value="st3">State10</option>
                        <option class="st3" value="st3">State11</option>
                        <option class="st3" value="st3">State12</option>
                        <option class="st4" value="st4">State13</option>
                        <option class="st4" value="st4">State14</option>
                        <option class="st4" value="st4">State15</option>
                        <option class="st4" value="st4">State16</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>City:
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ContactNo:
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dept. Name:
                    <input type="text" name="dept" id="dept" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Designation:
                    <input type="text" name="desig" id="desig" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Username:
                    <input type="text" name="empuser" id="empuser" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Re-enter Password:
            <inputtype="password"name="conpass"id="conpass"onchange="checkpassword()"required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
<div class"formalert" id="passcheck"></div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    <button id="submit">Register</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </form>
    <td>
    <form action="./emplogin.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Back"/>
    </form></td>
<div id="ack"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**updatedetails.php**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include '../db/dbconn.php';
    //escape variables for security
    if (isset($_POST['empname'])) {
        $empname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['empname']);
    } else {
        $empname = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    } else {
        $email = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['addr'])) {
        $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['addr']);
    } else {
        $address = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
    } else {
        $country = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['state'])) {
        $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['state']);
    } else {
        $state = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
    } else {
        $city = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
    } else {
        $phone = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['dept'])) {
        $dept = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dept']);
    } else {
        $dept = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['desig'])) {
        $desig = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['desig']);
    } else {
        $desig = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['empuser'])) {
        $empuser = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['empuser']);
    } else {
        $empuser = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $emppass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['pass']));
    } else {
        $emppass = "";
    }
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT empuser FROM empdetails WHERE empuser='$empuser'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    if ($row > 0) {
        echo "Username $empuser already exists";
    } else {


        //inserting data into database


$sql="INSERTINTOempdetails(empname,email,address,country,state,city,phone,dept,desig,empuser,emp)            
 VALUES('$empname','$email','$address','$country','$state','$city','$phone','$dept',
'$desig',
'$empuser',
'$emppass')";
        if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
            //error detected
        } else {
            echo "Records inserted sucessfully";
            //no errors
        }
    }
?>
<br />
    <br />
    Click <a href="emplogin.php">here</a> to login
</body>
</html>
```

**Database design:**

table_empdetails
1.empid int A_I PK unsigned 
2.empname varchar 
3.email varchar
4.address varchar
5.country varchar
6.state varchar
7.city varchar
8.phone int unsigned
9.dept varchar
10.desig varchar
11.empuser varchar unique
12.emppass varchar

Comment: It means, you are trying to insert to the table in database in field, which has unique (or primary) key and such value for that key already exists...

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, you are trying to insert values which already exists in the database tables which is primary key.

Comment: @seenu09 , Post your Database schema and with key values.

Comment: @Harry I have given primary key to column_name: 'empid' and unique key to column_name: 'empuser' and the database is completely empty.

Comment: @seenu09 post your schema and key values

Comment: Hello @Harry I have edited and updated the database design

Comment: I removed unique key for column 'empuser' and tried to execute.Its displaying "records inserted sucessfully" but when checked in database no data is updated.All the fields are empty.

Comment: have you tried debugging? to check the values in the variables declared are being passed correctly into insert?

Comment: I think this is your problem you sayin isset($_POST['pass'])) when in your insert statement the value is emp and variable is @emppass, make this change if (isset($_POST['emp'])) {
        $emppass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['emppass']));
    } else {
        $emppass = "";
    } Let me know if this fixed it.

Comment: No @Harry The error now showing is username already existed though the database table is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66028/discussion-between-harry-and-seenu09).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, need to change

```
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $emppass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['pass']));
    } else {
        $emppass = "";
    }
```

**To**

```
if (isset($_POST['emp'])) { 
           $emppass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['emppass'])); 
        } else { 
           $emppass = ""; 
        }
```

This will pass the parameters into the query at

```
$sql="INSERTINTOempdetails(empname,email,address,country,state,city,phone,dept,desig,empuser,emp)            
 VALUES('$empname','$email','$address','$country','$state','$city','$phone','$dept',
'$desig',
'$empuser',
'$emppass')";
```